# What * symbol means in this objective-c functionNSString *NSTemporaryDirectory(void)?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, pointers

What does the * symbol means placed before the function name (function is defined in NSPathUtilities.h category extension for Foundation framework:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSTemporaryDirectory(void);
```

Thanks!

Comment: NSString * means "NSString pointer", some folks put a space between the * and Function identifier to perhaps make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function returns a pointer to an NSString. Since Objective-C is based on C, the syntax uses pointers to objects rather than objects themselves. For example, to declare a string variable you would use:

```
NSString *myString;
```

rather than

```
NSString myString;
```

Comment: but shouldn't it be like: *NSString NSTemporaryDirectory(void); in objective-c you put the * sign before the variable name, otherwise x-code marks it as error?

Comment: No, that's not the way C works. A pointer to an integer is `int *myIntegerPointer;` A pointer to a structure is `SomeRecordType *myRecordPointer;`.